# Knowing std::once_flag is used without invoking std::call_once (Set once_flag after task finishes successfully)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, initialization

Edit: this is an XY Problem but keep the original title as well. It might help other people having the same XY problem. The goal should be: "have `std::once_flag` flipped only after the task is successfully finished."

#### Use case

1. Initialization needs to be done just once and it might be called concurrently.
2. Before calling the initialization, validation needs to be done.
3. If it's already initialized, validation is not required.

#### Question

How do I not using `g_init`(in the below sample) while avoiding the `filesystem::exists()` check after initialization?

#### Restriction

1. I cannot modify caller which is a infrastructure that I cannot change.
2. `cfg["PATH"]` is unknown and it can only be supplied by caller.

Welcome C++20 or C++23 and other solutions. It's good to be standard or homemade solution.
Also it might be an XY problem...

A simplified [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MejP19dK8)

```
#include <mutex>
#include <filesystem>
#include <atomic>
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json;
std::once_flag g_flag;
std::atomic<bool> g_init{false};

void doOnce(std::string path){
    // initializing from file...
    fmt::print("initialization done");
}

void doWork(json& cfg){
    // Atomic flag for 
    if(g_init) {
        fmt::print("already inited");
        return;
    }

    std::string path = cfg["PATH"];
    if(!std::filesystem::exists(path)){
        fmt::print("load failed");
        return;
    }
    std::call_once(g_flag, doOnce, path);
}

int main() {
    json cfg;
    cfg["PATH"] = "/opt/usr/foo";

    // In the real world case, caller will call it
    // with random values and PATH might not exist.
    doWork(cfg);
}
```

It seems that [`std::once_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) doesn't expose anything to know whether it's called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the problem `call_once` is supposed to solve. If you let it do it's job it'll handle all this for you. If you throw an exception when initialisation fails `call_once` will run again:

```
void doOnce(std::string path){
    if(!std::filesystem::exists(path)){
        throw std::runtime_error("load failed");
    }
    // initializing from file...
    fmt::print("initialization done");
}

void doWork(json& cfg){
    std::string path = cfg["PATH"];
    try
    {
        std::call_once(g_flag, doOnce, path);
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        fmt::print(ex.what());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks for guiding the direction! I read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and find "If that invocation throws an exception, it is propagated to the caller of std::call_once, and flag is not flipped so that another call will be attempted (such a call to std::call_once is known as exceptional )." That's easy to miss! ( to me )

Answer (score 0):

Having some kind of globals is always tough for maintainence (hard to refactor later) and unit testability. Learn to use dependency injection, make an interface for your config data and inject that into code that needs config info. This approach avoids globals, makes code unit testable AND you can later easily change to other ways of getting your config without having to change anything in other parts of the code. Example :

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

// Your code wants config data, not a JSON file
// and JSON is just one way of creating configuration info
// abstract away from it by modeling an interface
// for access to your configuration data
// this will make your code testable (without even having
// actual JSON files during testing)
struct config_itf
{
    virtual int get_value1() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual const std::string& get_name1() const noexcept = 0;
};

struct config_t : 
    public config_itf
{
    int get_value1() const noexcept override
    {
        return value1;
    }

    const std::string& get_name1() const noexcept override
    {
        return name;
    }

    int value1{ 42 };
    std::string name{ "hello world!" };
};

std::unique_ptr<config_itf> load_from_JSON(std::string_view filename)
{
    std::unique_ptr<config_itf> config{ std::make_unique<config_t>() };
    // todo load from file
    // throw if something fails
    return config;
}

class some_class_t
{
public:
    // pass interface by reference it MUST be
    // a valid instance
    explicit some_class_t(config_itf& config)
        // use config data here
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    // create only once early on in main
    auto config_ptr = load_from_JSON("config.json");

    // then later inject interface(!) into constructors of classes that need
    // config info (in tests this allows you to inject preprogrammed classes
    // with e.g. a bad config without needing to rely on filesystem
    // which can introduce test failurs of its own)
    some_class_t some_class{ *config_ptr };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do just like your suggestion when it could be loaded on init, but the real case is that I can only wait for that json afterward...

Comment: Then you can have a flag in your config struct that it is not valid yet. And load the json later. Makes for some interesting test cases too ;)